# CakePHP Advanced Auth and Session Handling

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, session-management

I'm looking for an advanced CakePHP authentification component or plugin. I've used the core [auth plugin](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html) and it's fine. I'm however looking for something a bit more advanced that allow to keep track of multiple sessions for the same user. Main features/reasons would be: Ability for user to see active sessions and allow the user to end active sessions. This method is used by [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&section=sessions&view) and other large sites.

If you do not know of an Auth component that does what I mentioned above do you know of any Auth component that does more than CakePHP's core/built-in component?

I searched the CakePHP bakery section and Googled to find an Auth component but didn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is something built-in for Auth in CakePHP with that complexity, try this plugin

https://github.com/Theaxiom/SuperAuth

Or check in the official github repository from CakeDC team https://github.com/CakeDC

also try to find something in http://plugins.cakephp.org/

By the way, maybe you can ask directly to core guys on irc ;) go to http://webchat.freenode.net/ and channel cakephp.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll check out plugins.cakephp.org and the irc. SuperAuth isn't really what I'm looking for but thanks for mentioning it.